# How to pass dictionary values in UIAlertView?

Tags: objective-c, uialertview, nsmutabledictionary

I have this dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary *responseDict = [responseString objectFromJSONString];
```

```
{"order_processed":"N","m_fname":"zohaib","m_lname":"sheikh",
"mobile_number":"02343434343","enterd_balance":"610","paid":"Y",
"operator":"Mobilink"}
```

How can I show my Dict key and values in `UIAlertView`?

Comment: what do you want to show in alert view i mean which key values would you like to show?

Comment: like this :
name : Zohaib Sheikh
mobile number: 023434343
entered_balance: 610

in this way i want to show my values in UIAlertView

or just like :

Zohaib Sheikh
023434343
610

Comment: complete name
my number
and amount

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your values in NSString after getting response from JSON and then easily you can show them on alertview like this:

```
NSString *testValue1=@"zohaib";
NSString *testValue2=@"999988";
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your details" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name : %@ ,Number : %@",testValue1,testValue2] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No"  otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alertView setTag:102];
alertView.alertViewStyle =UIAlertViewStyleDefault;
[alertView show];
```

Please let me know if you mean the same ?

Comment: yes thankyou so much ASP, i really mean the same one

that is so kind of you 

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %@",[responseDict valueForKey:@"m_fname"],[responseDict valueForKey:@"m_lname"],[responseDict valueForKey:@"mobile_number"],[responseDict valueForKey:@"enterd_balance"]];

UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Your details" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No"  otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alertView show];
```

Answer (score 0):

A UIAlertView is probably not the best way to show this sort of data. While I do not know what your app does, I would probably use a UINavigationController to show a list of clients and tap down into a client detail ( http://simplecode.me/2011/09/04/an-introduction-to-uinavigationcontroller/ ). Or, if I were showing the results of an action, I would consider some sort of custom unobtrusive view to display and dismiss the data.

The reason being that UIAlertViews are *very* jarring to the user. Additionally, while you can display a lot of information in them, they are generally not well suited for displaying lots of data.

That being said, to display any text in an UIAlert, you must first construct an NSString. Here's a string being constructed with the values of two keys from a dictionary:

```
NSString *alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat@"%@ %@", [dictionary valueForKey:@"firstKey"], [dictionary valueForKey:@"secondKey"]];
```

The string would then be used as the message or title in a UIAlert:

```
UIAlert *alert = [[UIAlert alloc] initWithTitle:@"Payment results"
                                        message:alertText
                                       delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                              otherButtonTitles:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

You would then call show to display the alert. Be sure to read the [UIAlertView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) for additional methods, how to add additional buttons and how to respond to user input.